# test an array with std::is_sorted, but with a preset accuracy

Tags: c++, std

It's all in the title.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int n=12;
    double x[n];

    x[0]=-0.717778;
    x[1]=-0.496843;
    x[2]=-0.429063;
    x[3]=-0.3596;
    x[4]=-0.205607;
    x[5]=0.0730536;
    x[6]=0.138018;
    x[7]=0.585526;
    x[8]=2.40104;
    x[9]=3.752680001;   //here
    x[10]=3.75268;
    x[11]=4.55704;

    std::cout << std::is_sorted(x,x+n) << std::endl;

}
```

basically, I would like it to return 1 (for true):
 although I can see that `x[9]` *is* larger than `x[10]`, 
the difference between them is smaller than `1e-8` 
so I take them to be equal.

Comment: I would use something like `std::adjacent_find(begin(x), end(x), [epsilon](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {lhs > rhs + epsilon}) == end(x)`.

Comment: What if you have a series that's completely in reverse order, but each element is only `1e-8` greater than the next? Would you want that to be reported as sorted?

Comment: @Jarod42: I hear, but how?, Benjamin Lindley: then I would want it to return TRUE (1) as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard library algorithm which will do this exactly, but `std::is_sorted_until` will help.

```
bool sorted = true;
auto b = std::begin(x), e = std::end(x);
while (true)
{
    b = std::is_sorted_until(b,e);
    if (b == e)
        break;
    if (b[-1] - b[0] > epsilon)
    {
        sorted = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Although this might just be overcomplicating things. Maybe a straightforward loop with no standard algorithms will be simpler.

```
bool sorted = true;
auto b = std::begin(x), e = std::end(x) - 1;
while (b < e)
{
    if (b[0] - b[1] > epsilon)
    {
        sorted = false;
        break;
    }
    ++b;
}
```

Yep, that's simpler.

Answer (score 7):

I would use (C++14):

```
std::adjacent_find(
    std::begin(x),
    std::end(x),
    [epsilon](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs > rhs + epsilon;})
    == std::end(x);
```

as `is_sorted` would be misleading.

or in C++11:

```
std::adjacent_find(
    std::begin(x),
    std::end(x),
    [epsilon](const double& lhs, const double& rhs) { return lhs > rhs + epsilon;})
    == std::end(x);
```

Comment: `is_sorted` just plainly is not applicable because the comparison does not define an order because transitivity is violated.

Comment: @Jarod42, the problem with the `adjacent_find` solution is that it finds elements that are "equal" next to each other, but says nothing for the overall sorted (in this case "almost sorted") of the container. If the first element is larger (to more than the `epsilon`) than the second, how would this be handled?

Comment: @Niall: It finds the element with is *greater* than the next element, (and so the element which proves that the list is not "*sorted*"). if there are no such element (`== std::end(x)`), then the array is sorted according to OP.

Comment: @Jarod42: This makes an assumption about which element (the first or the second) `adjacent_find` passes to which argument position of the comparator. I don't think the specification makes any promises on that. Although I may be mistaken, I don't have the standard in front of me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/) seems to indicate that it is specified that way... but [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) don't.

Comment: @Jarod42. Not sure on the websites, but n3797 says this "Returns: The first iterator `i` such that both `i` and `i + 1` are in the range `[first,last)` for which the following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == *(i + 1)`, `pred(*i, *(i + 1)) != false`. Returns
last if no such iterator is found." § 25.2.8/1

Comment: @Niall: Thanks for the ref, so my solution is correct :-)

Comment: @Jarod42, and neat. Wrap it all up in a `almost_sorted` function and bake it at 220 for 35 minutes... +1